# Problem trying to add Refresh option to Right click menu

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, nautilus, ppa

I am trying to add Refresh option to Right click menu in ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I tried with the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dr3mro/nautilus-actions-extra
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-refresh
```

but throws an error "PPA is obsolete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **nautilus actions extra** project page on launchpad, "This PPA is obselete and will not recieve any new updates", so you need to use Official Release PPA: **ppa:nae-team/ppa**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-refresh
```

Reference: https://launchpad.net/nautilus-actions-extra